# how can i insert an html page in a react component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm still learning about react and I need to know how I could insert an external HTML page (index.html) to my react app in a component. In other words, this index.html shows an online text editor with all its functionalities and I need that editor to be displayed in a component of my react app

---

```
index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Web Application -->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Texture Editor</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>
      @import '../texture.css';
      @import '../texture-reset.css';
      @import '../lib/katex/katex.min.css';
      @import '../lib/inter-ui/inter.css';
      @import '../lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';
      body { overflow: hidden; }
      html, body { height: 100%; }
      .sc-app {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/substance/substance.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./lib/katex/katex.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./texture.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../plugins/texture-plugin-jats/texture-plugin-jats.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./demo/vfs.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./demo/demo.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe you can use WebView or you can convert the html into jsx format

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to mess around with `index.html` much, you could use an `iframe`. Copy the `index.html` (you may have to rename this) file to the public folder load it in to the `iframe`

```js
const Iframe = src => <iframe src={src} height="500" width="500"/>;

ReactDOM.render(
  <Iframe src="http://localhost:3000/index.html" />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```